# Is it possible for Swagger to show a different model view for POST and PATCH, ie for write-once property?

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle

I'm writing an API in ASPNET Core and using Swashbuckle to auto-generate a Swagger doc from code.

I'd really like to offer different views of the model, because some model properties are 'write-once' values that should be submitted on a POST when creating the resource, but should not be sent on a PATCH, as the value cannot be modified.

At the moment I have attributes on the model properties, which allow me to tag a property as `Readable`, `Writable` or `Editable`, and when `Editable=false` the value should not appear in a PATCH request, but is valid in a GET or POST)

I've coded a custom [ISchemaFilter](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/138) so that I can set `ReadOnly=true` on the schema where my attribute is `Writable=false`, but `Editable` is a quirky one where I'd like it to appear on POST but not on PATCH, and I don't think I can do that in the ISchema filter...

Is this possible without creating separate models for POST and PATCH?